# How do I display a cutom tooltip on google candlestick chart?

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I am using google charts in an angular2 environment (used this answer to get going: [Angular2 + Google Charts. How to integrate Google Charts in Angular2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37542408/angular2-google-charts-how-to-integrate-google-charts-in-angular2)).  My chart options are set up as follows:

```
chartType: 'CandlestickChart',
options: {
    backgroundColor : '#101010',
    legend: 'none',
    chartArea: {'width': '85%', 'height': '75%'},
    height: 700,
    colors: ['#aaaaaa'],
    textStyle: {color: 'white'},
    tooltip: {isHtml: true},
    slantedText: true,
    slantedTextAngle: 90,
    candlestick: {
        fallingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#a52714' }, // red
        risingColor: { strokeWidth: 0, fill: '#0f9d58' }   // green
    },
    vAxis: {
        title :'price',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        textStyle: {color: 'white'}
    },
    hAxis: {
        title: '',
        titleTextStyle: {
            color: 'white'
        },
        slantedText: true,
        slantedTextAngle: 90,
        textStyle: {color: 'white'},
    }
},
dataTable: [['Date', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'High', 'tooltip']]
```

Then when I add the rows, I do it as follows:

```
rows.push([data[index].endOfCurrentCandleTime, data[index].low, data[index].open, data[index].close, data[index].high, this.createCustomHTMLContent()]);
```

However, I just get this error:

> Last domain does not have enough data columns (missing 3)

How do I get google charts to recognise that the last column is the custom tooltip?

BTW - I've looked at this ([Custom tooltip text in Candlestick chart of google charts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872096/custom-tooltip-text-in-candlestick-chart-of-google-charts)) and it didn't help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

need to define the tooltip column's `role`...

try this...

`dataTable: [['Date', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'High', {role: 'tooltip'}]]`

for `html` tooltips...

`dataTable: [['Date', 'Low', 'Open', 'Close', 'High', {role: 'tooltip', p: {html: true}}]]`

Comment: Great - thanks.  Its working.  The html part is not working.  Just takes the html tags and shows them.  (e.g. <div><ul><li>......)

Comment: had to add this to the options:  tooltip: {isHtml: true},

Comment: I had removed it - all working really nicely now.  Thanks for your help

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Can you please advise what am I doing wrong?
You can find my question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53428980/ng2-google-charts-doesnt-show-the-correct-tooltip
Thanks!