# ng2-google-charts doesn't show the correct tooltip

Tags: angular, charts, google-visualization

I am using `ng2-google-charts` to create a Timeline chart and I want to display a custom tooltip - it's not too complicated, I just want to display a different value depending on some conditions. This is my code:

Component:

```
chartData:any =  {
    chartType: 'Timeline',
    dataTable: [
        ['Name', 'From', 'To', {role: 'tooltip'}]
    ]
}

this.chartData.dataTable.push([x.values.name, x.values.dateFrom, x.values.dateTo, item.values.organization]);
```

The problem is that the tooltip displays the value from the `Name` column and not the value from the last column which is defined to be used as a tooltip.
So into the tooltip I would like to see the value of `item.values.organization` and not `x.values.name` (which is currently showing).
Please advise what am I doing wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the timeline chart, the tooltip column needs to be in a certain position.

every row of your datatable must have all five columns,
row label, bar label, tooltip, start, and end -- **in that order**.

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  'packages': ['timeline']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var container = document.getElementById('timeline-tooltip');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
  var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'President'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    id: 'dummy bar label'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'string',
    role: 'tooltip'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'Start'
  });
  dataTable.addColumn({
    type: 'date',
    id: 'End'
  });
  dataTable.addRows([
    ['Washington', null, 'George', new Date(1789, 3, 29), new Date(1797, 2, 3)],
    ['Adams', null, 'John', new Date(1797, 2, 3), new Date(1801, 2, 3)],
    ['Jefferson', null, 'Thomas', new Date(1801, 2, 3), new Date(1809, 2, 3)]
  ]);

  chart.draw(dataTable);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="timeline-tooltip"></div>
```